# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline using Visual Studio Build Error SQL71006

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

We are currently using RedGate with Azure DevOps in our build pipeline.  I'm creating a new build pipeline using Visual Studio Build.  The build is throwing error SQL71006 "Only one statement is allowed per batch.  A batch separator, such as 'GO', might be required between statements."

The sql that's failing is a CREATE TABLE with a CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX after - no GO between the two.  If I add a GO between the two it works.  However, our current pipeline using RedGate does not fail with this code.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Build to ignore this error?  We have thousands of files that would need to be updated if we can't.

Comment: Which RedGate tools are you using in your build? From "[SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver16)": `GO` is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the **sqlcmd** and **osql** utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I'm not sure which RedGate tools we are using, I'll have to look that up.  All I know is when I created a build pipeline in DevOps using MSBuild (VSBuild@1), when it encounters that CREATE TABLE sql, it errors out because there isn't a GO between the statements.  I want the build to ignore that error.  Is that possible?

Comment: I'm guessing the RedGate tools you are using have their own means of talking to SQL Server and the statement batch behavior is different. When this error occurs, are the SQL statements run anyway? I assume they are not. I found this article - [SQL GO command in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-go-command-in-sql-server/) - which may help. It may be that a GO should be added after each CREATE statement but I'm speculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Build to ignore this error?

Not sure about your project structure. But we can use the `ContinueOnError` attribute to ignore errors in MSBuild tasks. See [Ignore errors in tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-ignore-errors-in-tasks?view=vs-2022) for details.

If you are using VSBuild task in pipeline, we can enable the [control option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#task-control-options) "`continueOnError: true`" like this:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: 'xxxx'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  continueOnError: true
```

If that doesn't work for you and the SQL scripts don't need to be included in the build process, then you can change your project file and set the `Build Action` property to `None` for the scripts.

For example:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="Tables\Customer.sql" />
    <None Include="Scripts\RunPostScriptsGenerated.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**UPDATE:**

I can reproduce the issue when setting the `Build Action` property to `Build` for the affected SQL script. See the screenshot for details.

[image]

And after I change the `Build Action` property to `None`, everything works as expected.

[image]

So, please try building the project locally using Visual Studio to determine which files need the properties changed. Then change the `Build Action` property to `None` for all the affected files. After that try it again to see if it works in pipeline.

**UPDATE2:**

Per Rich's comment the issue has been resolved by changing the `.sqlproj` file.

> In the ItemGroup, change it from having a Build Include line for every
> file to just one per folder using `*.sql`. This worked: `<Build Include="Stored Procedures\*.sql" />`

Comment: I tried both of these and neither will work, the sql causing the error will not get into the .dacpac file, which I'm guessing means it won't get deployed with the Release pipeline.

I'm new to this so not sure of my structure.  In Visual Studio I created a SQL Server Database Project.  I then added all of my files to the project, committed it back to my DevOps branch and ran the build.  I don't think I've done anything special to the project.

Comment: @RichUchytil Please try changing the properties of all files (SQL scripts) you added to the project, just set the `Build Action` to `None`. And then try it again. See the updated answer.

Comment: I just tried that.  The build was successful, that error didn't show.  But none of the files are in the .dacpac.  When I do a deployment, will anything get deployed?  Do files have to be in the .dacpac to be deployed?  And I'm doing this through Azure DevOps using a build pipeline, not Visual Studio.

Comment: I think I found the answer.  In the .sqlproj file, in the ItemGroup, change it from having a Build Include line for every file to just one per folder using *.sql.  This worked:
`<Build Include="Stored Procedures\*.sql" />`

Comment: Actually, that's an answer to another question I had.  What I want to do is have the build pipeline build everything, just ignore this GO error.  Saying NONE means it is ignoring that file when the build runs, and if I'm understanding right, that means it won't get deployed.

Comment: @RichUchytil Glad to know that you have resolved the issue and thanks for sharing the solution. I have updated the answer with your solution. You can accept it or post your own answer and accept it. BTW, actually it's a MSBuild issue here, if it can be built locally (via Visual Studio), then it can also be built in pipeline, as it calls the msbuild command in pipeline. For msbuild, no available options to only ignore the GO error here. However, we can troubleshoot against the project as you did, or write another script to include all the needed files/scripts to be deployed.